# Church numerals: How should I interpret the numbers from expressions?

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-encoding

Can someone explain to me using substitutions how we get a number "zero" or the rest of natural numbers?

For example the value: "zero"

```
λf.λx.x
```

if I apply this expression on an another expression:

```
"(λf.(λx.x)) a"
```

then using substitution:

```
:=[a/f](λx.x)
:=(λx.x)
```

what am I missing? How should I interpret these number expressions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by how you zero. `λf.λx.x` *is* zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The church numeral `n` is a function that takes another function `f` and returns a function that applies `f` to its argument `n` times. So `0 a` (where `0` is, as you said, `λf.λx.x`
) returns `λx.x` because that applies `a` to `x` 0 times.

`1 a` gives you `λx. a x`, `2 a` gives you `λx. a (a x)` and so on.

Comment: explained very well: http://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/311/Readings/supplemental.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Below is the explanation based on [paper](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/311/Readings/supplemental.pdf) by [Erhan Bagdemir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481863/erhan-bagdemir) in the comment to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17924805/8554766) by [sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149392/sepp2k).

Essential points to grasp:

- all Church numerals are functions of two parameters;
- for Church numerals, it is implied that:

  - `f` — is the 'successor' function (i.e. function which accepts a Church numeral and return church numeral next one, **it's basically and increment**);
  - `x` — is a (Church numeral) value representing 'zero' (the **count starting point**).

Keeping that in mind:

```
λf . λx . x
```

will be equal to zero, if we will pass the appropriate `f` (*in this particular case it doesn't matter what function will be passed as `f`, since it never applied*) and `x`:

```
λf . λx . ZERO
```

following:

```
λf . λx .  fx
```

will be evaluated to 1:

```
λf . λx . INCREMENT ZERO
```

and this:

```
λf . λx . f f x
```

will be qual to 2:

```
λf . λx . INCREMENT(INCREMENT ZERO)
```

and so on, for all the successive numbers.

See my [(broader) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48928043/8554766) to another (but closely related) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978590/why-the-definition-of-churchs-numerals).

Answer (score 0):

A church numeral n, (say 2,) represents the "action" of applying any given function n times (here,two times) on any given parameter.

A church numeral, by definition, is a function that takes two parameters, namely
1) a function
 
2) a parameter or expression or value on which the supplied  function is applied.

When the supplied function is the successor function, and the supplied second parameter is Zero , you get the numeral. (2, in the above example)

Church numeral 2 is by definition,

```
λf . λx . f( f( x))
```

,Which is obviously a function that takes two parameters.

On passing the successor function, i.e f(x)=x+1  as first parameter and zero as second parameter to the function, we get...

```
f(f(0))  
=f(1) 
=2
```

This explanation is kinda simplified as definition of  successor function and zero aren't as shown, in lambda calculus..

Refer :http://www.cse.unt.edu/~tarau/teaching/GPL/docs/Church%20encoding.pdf
An excellent explanation on church encodings