# Why the definition of Church's Numerals

Tags: lambda-calculus

I want to understand, why Church define the numerals like:

```
0 = λ f . λ x . x
1 = λ f . λ x . f x
2 = λ f . λ x . f f x
3 = λ f . λ x . f f f x
4 = λ f . λ x . f f f f x
```

What is the logic behind?

Why 0 is represent like:

```
0 = λ f . λ x . x
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure mathematics question with only a tangential application to programming. It is certainly not a *practical programming problem*, as required by Stack Overflow's rules. You might try asking on [Math.SE], instead.

Comment: @CodyGray Given the existence of tags such as `lambda-calculus`, `turing-machines`, etc., it isn't very plausible to claim that questions about the foundations of computing are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If they were, at least half a dozen tags would have to be removed. There isn't any sharp borderline between math and computer science. Lambda calculus is in the fuzzy area where they overlap.

Comment: @john In my opinion, the overlap is supposed to be where you are asking about these concepts in the context of a programming problem. That's why the tags exist. It isn't black and white, of course, but as I said, this seems like a pure math question, which makes it not programming. There is also a [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) Q&A site, which may be a better home for this question. In general, I believe that such abstract CS questions are off-topic here, but you are free to disagree.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree that the theoretical computer science site might be a better home for questions such as this, but that doesn't imply that they should be forbidden here. Since at least some people might search the lambda calculus tag to try to get a better understanding of Church numbers (perhaps as part of a programming project), occasional questions like this might serve some purpose.

Comment: Want to mention a nice paper about the topic: https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ralf.hinze/publications/Church.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Church wasn't trying to be practical. He was trying to prove results about the expressive power of lambda calculus — that in principle any possible computation can be done in lambda calculus, hence lambda calculus can serve as a theoretical foundation for the study of computability. In order to do so, it was necessary to *encode* numbers as lambda expressions, in such a way that things like the successor function are easily definable. This was a key step in showing the equivalence of lambda calculus and [Gödel's recursive function theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Computer_language_definition) (which was about computable functions on the natural numbers). Church numerals are basically a convenient albeit not very readable encoding of numbers. In some sense, there isn't any very deep logic to it. The claim isn't that 1 in its essence *is* `λ f . λ x . f x`, but that the latter is a serviceable encoding of the former.

This doesn't mean that it is an *arbitrary* encoding. There is a definite logic to it. The most natural way to encode a number `n` is by something which involves `n`. Church numerals use `n` function applications. The natural number `n` is represented by the higher order function which applies a function `n` times to an input. `1` is encoded by a function applied once, `2` by a function applied twice and so on. It is a very natural encoding, especially in the context of lambda calculus. Furthermore, the fact that it is easy to define arithmetic on them streamlines the proof that lambda calculus is equivalent to recursive functions.

To see this in practice, you can run the following Python3 script:

```
#some Church numerals:

ZERO = lambda f: lambda x: x
ONE = lambda f: lambda x: f(x)
TWO = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(x))
THREE = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(f(x)))

#function to apply these numerals to:

def square(x): return x**2

#so ZERO(square), ONE(square), etc. are functions
#apply these to 2 and print the results:

print(ZERO(square)(2), ONE(square)(2), TWO(square)(2),THREE(square)(2))
```

Output:

```
2 4 16 256
```

Note that these numbers have been obtained by squaring the number two 0 times, 1 times, 2 times, and 3 times respectively.

Comment: Aha ok, it is just a convention to represent a natural numbers. Thanks s a lot.

Comment: @zero_coding I was probably a bit too glib about it being just an encoding. It is an encoding as opposed to e.g. a theorem which captures the essence of natural numbers, but it is far from being *just* a convention.

Comment: `The natural number n is represented by the higher order function which applies a function n times to an input` could you show me an example please.

Comment: @zero_coding for fun I threw in a Python example.

Comment: Python snippet, really, made it clear for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), a natural number is either 0 or *S*(*n*) for another natural number *n*:

```
0 = 0
1 = S(0)
2 = S(S(0))
...
```

You can see Church numerals as a generalization of Peano numbers, where you provide your own 0 and *S*:

```
0 = λs.λz. z
1 = λs.λz. s(z)
2 = λs.λz. s(s(z))
...
```

Since this is a programming forum, let's create some Church numerals in EcmaScript 6:

```
const ZERO = s => z => z;
const ONE  = s => z => s(z);
const TWO  = s => z => s(s(z));
...
```

You can convert these Church numerals to JavaScript numbers by providing the appropriate zero and successor:

```
function toInt(n) {
    return n(i => i + 1)(0);
}
```

And then:

```
> toInt(TWO)
2
```

You could use Church numerals to do some practical things:

```
function shout(text) {
    return text + "!";
}

> shout("hi")
"hi!"
> NINE(shout)("hi")
"hi!!!!!!!!!"
```

​

You can try it here: https://es6console.com/iyoim5y8/

Answer (score 3):

The following [paper](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/311/Readings/supplemental.pdf) by [Robert (Corky) Cartwright](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~cork/) broke it down for me very well.

Essential points to grasp, for the very beginning:

- all Church numerals are functions with two parameters;
- in the Church representation of any number, it is implied that:

  - `f` — is the 'successor' function (i.e. function which accepts a Church numeral and returns church numeral next to the passed one, **it's basically and increment**);
  - `x` — is a (Church numeral) value representing 'zero' (the **count starting point**).

Keeping that in mind:

```
λf . λx . x
```

will be equal to zero, if we will pass the appropriate `f` ('successor' —increment function) and `x` ('zero' — count starting point). *In this particular case it doesn't matter what function will be passed as `f`, since it never applied*:

```
λf . λx . ZERO
```

this:

```
λf . λx .  fx
```

will be evaluated to 1:

```
λf . λx . INCREMENT ZERO
```

and the following:

```
λf . λx . f f x
```

will be qual to 2:

```
λf . λx . INCREMENT(INCREMENT ZERO)
```

and so on, for all the successive numbers.

---

**Bonus** (addition, multiplication and exponentiation of Church numerals):

Here is a Python code snippet to illustrate (and expand on) said above:

```
ZERO = lambda f: lambda x: x
ONE = lambda f: lambda x: f(x)
TWO = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(x))
THREE = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(f(x)))

SUCC = lambda x: x + 1

ADD = lambda f: lambda x: lambda n: lambda m: n(f)(m(f)(x))
MULT = lambda f: lambda x: lambda n: lambda m: n(m(f))(x)
EXPON = lambda m: lambda n: n(m)
```

`ADD` exploits the fact that any Church numeral accepts a 'zero' count starting point, as it's argument — it just counts to `n` starting with `m`. So, `ADD(SUCC)(0)(THREE)(TWO)` will just count to 3, but starting with 2, thus giving us `2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5`.

`MULT` utilizes the fact that a 'successor' function is just an argument of a Church numeral, and thus could be replaced. Thus `MULT(SUCC)(0)(TWO)(THREE)` will return 3 twice, which is the same as `2 * 3 = 6`.

`EXPON` is a bit tricky (it was for myself, at least), the key **point here is to keep track of what is getting returned by what**. What it, basically, does — is uses the intrinsic mechanism of Church numerals representation (recursion of `f` application, in particular). Here are some examples to illustrate:

3<sup>0</sup>

```
EXPON(THREE)(ZERO)(SUCC)(0)
↓
lambda n: n(THREE)(ZERO)(SUCC)(0)
↓
ZERO(THREE)(SUCC)(0)
↓
lambda x: (SUCC)(0)
↓
SUCC(0)
↓
1
```

3<sup>1</sup>

```
EXPON(THREE)(ONE)(SUCC)(0)
↓
lambda n: n(THREE)(ONE)(SUCC)(0)
↓
ONE(THREE)(SUCC)(0)
↓
lambda x: THREE(x)(SUCC)(0)
↓
THREE(SUCC)(0)
↓
3
```

1<sup>3</sup>

```
EXPON(ONE)(THREE)(SUCC)(0)
↓
lambda n: n(ONE)(THREE)(SUCC)(0)
↓
THREE(ONE)(SUCC)(0)
↓
lambda x: ONE(ONE(ONE(x)))(SUCC)(0)
↓
ONE(ONE(ONE(SUCC)))(0)
↓
ONE(ONE(lambda x: SUCC(x)))(0)
↓
lambda x:(lambda x: (lambda x: SUCC(x)) (x))(x)(0)
↓
SUCC(0)
↓
1
```